# Como renomear todas as tabelas de um banco MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho um banco MySQL com varias tabelas e estou migrando para outra base de dados.

> Tenho Cliente e dever ficar Cliente_PE
>
> Tenho Produto e dever ficar Produto_PE

Como posso realizar isso sem contudo me detenha a renomear cada uma das 50 tabelas?

Comment: As tabelas já estão populadas? Em dois passos é simples, você faz um select para pegar o nome das tabelas, e gera uma saída com `concat( 'rename table ', nome, ' to ', nome, '_PE' )`. Aí basta pegar essa saída e executar como uma query.

Comment: Você que adicionar o posfixo na tabela isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo...um posfixo nas tabelas!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**O jeito mais fácil**, já que 50 é um número não tão grande de linhas:

```
RENAME TABLE
    Cliente TO Cliente_PE,
    Produto TO Produto_PE,
    TabelaX TO TabelaX_PE
```

<sub>Veja o [manual do SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html).</sub>

Você também pode fazer isso usando o `phpmyadmin`, mas aí você estará adicionando um prefixo às tabelas (PE_Cliente, etc):

1. Selecione o banco de dados que contém as tabelas no menu lateral.
2. Marque o checkbox `Check All`.
3. No select ao lado selecione `Add prefix to table`.
4. No campo "Add prefix" digite `prefix_`, no seu caso, `PE_`.

[image: Adicionar prefixo à uma tabela com o phpmyadmin]

Comment: Interessante essa função do phpmyadmin

Comment: Aliás, seria uma boa sugestão pros devs do phpmyadmin uma opção de sufixo também. Provavelmente seria só um mínimo ajuste na função de prefixo.

Answer (score 19):

Para renomear uma tabela, você utiliza o comando

```
RENAME TABLE nomeOriginal TO nomeNovo
```

Como são muitas tabelas, você pode usar esta query para gerar todos os `RENAME`s automaticamente:

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(
      'RENAME TABLE `', table_schema, '`.`', table_name,
      '` TO `', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '_PE`;' )
FROM
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema="NomeDoDb";
```

Saída exemplo:

```
RENAME TABLE `NomeDoDb`.`eventos` TO `NomeDoDb`.`eventos_PE`;
RENAME TABLE `NomeDoDb`.`fotos` TO `NomeDoDb`.`fotos_PE`;
RENAME TABLE `NomeDoDb`.`usuarios` TO `NomeDoDb`.`usuarios_PE`;
```

Aí basta pegar o resultado e executar como uma nova query, seja via *copy & paste*, redirecionando para um script SQL, etc.

Vantagens:

- Ela coloca um Sufixo nas tabelas, mas pode ser facilmente adaptada para prefixos ou misto;
- Evita digitar manualmente todos os nomes das tabelas;
- Fácil de excluir um grupo de tabelas filtrando no `WHERE` ou manualmente;
- Fácil de trabalhar em cima de mais de um DB usando a cláusula `WHERE`;
- Não depende de ferramenta específica, pode ser usado em linha de comando, ou mesmo em ferramentas visuais como MySQL workbench.
- Se precisar fazer isso periodicamente, pode criar uma `PROCEDURE`, e utilizar sempre que precisar, exemplo: `AdicionarSufixo( 'MeuDb', '_PE' );`

Answer (score 0):

No phpmyadmin (ou adminer), vá até "SQL" e digite o comando:

RENAME TABLE nome_atual TO novo_nome

Clique em executar. 
Após isso, dê F4 para atualizar a lista de tabelas do banco!